# How to subtract a data with nano-second in a same group

Tags: sql, time

When I execute

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
```

it gives me data under two columns `TIME` and `Order_Number`

```
====                ====
TIME                Order_Number
====                ====
100622.383          1202
100622.524          1202
100623.165          1202
100623.165          1202
```

What I want to get out of the query is to find the differnece between the `MAX(TIME)` and `MIN(TIME)`, which will be `100623.165 - 100622.383`

So what I tried was this,

```
SELECT MAX (TIME) - MIN (TIME) AS TIME_RESULT
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE ORDER_NUMBER='1202'
```

But the problem is that the dot in TIME column makes it a varchar type, so it won't substract.
The TIME formart is hour-min-sec. nano second.

Could anyone help me subtract the time that contains nano-second?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the format is hour-minute-second-millisecond.  Microseconds are way smaller.  And nanoseconds smaller yet again.

If these are representations of times, as strings, then you could convert them to native time data types.  That depends on the database.  You can also convert them to seconds, albeit with a lot of string manipulation:

```
select max(time_in_secs) - min(time_in_secs) as span_in_secs
from (select a.*,
             (cast(left(time, 2) as decimal(10, 3))*60*60 +
              cast(substring(time, 3, 2) as decimal(10, 3))*60 +
              cast(right(time, 6) as decimal(10, 3))
             ) as time_in_secs
      from table_a a
      where order_number = '1202'
     ) t;
```

The particular functions for manipulating the strings may depend on the database (such as `substr()` rather than `substring()`).  But the same logic (even with slightly different functions) can be applied in any database.